# The topological space $[0,1]$ is a continuous image of the Cantor space question.

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Prove that the topological space $[0,1]$ is a continuous image of the Cantor space $(G,T')$.

I know that this means to show there exists a function $$(i) f : (G,T') \rightarrow [0,1]$$ such that $f$ is continuous and onto and $$f(G) = [0,1]. $$  The book I'm reading says that:  *"In view of the fact that $$g : (G,T') \rightarrow (\prod^{\infty}_{i=1}A_i, T_i)$$ given by $$g(\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \frac{a_n}{3^n}) = <a_1, a_2, ..., a_n, ...>$$ where each $(A_i, T_i)$ is the set $\{0,2\}$ with the discrete topology, is a homeomorphism, it suffices to find a continuous mapping $\phi$ of $\prod^{\infty}_{i=1}(A_i, T_i)$ onto $[0,1]$."*

My question is:  Why does it suffice to show this instead of what I wanted to show in $(i)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H$ be the product space, and I will omit the topologies in the following.

Since you have a continuous, onto map $g : G\to H$, if you find a continuous, onto map $H\to [0,1]$, their composition will be a continuous, onto map $G\to [0,1]$. Which is what you wished to find.